# This method provide as the number of days between startDate and endDate excluding sat/sun. Can anyone explain me the meaning of If condition statement

Tags: apex

```
public static Integer getWorkingDays(Datetime startDate, Datetime endDate)
{
    Integer totalDays = 0;
    while(startDate<=endDate)
    {
        if(startDate.format('E')!='Sat' && startDate.format('E')!='Sun')
        {
            totalDays++;
        }
        startDate = startDate.addDays(1);
    }
    System.debug('Debug Statement :- ' + totalDays + ' Working Days');
    return totalDays;
}
```

Comment: I want to know what exactly " startDate.format('E')!='Sat' && startDate.format('E')!='Sun' "  is doing.

Comment: It is asking whether the given date (the updated `startDate`) is NOT a Saturday or Sunday and only then incrementing the total.

Comment: Side note: You can use BusinessHours to easily calculate working days without potentially expensive loops.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per the [Java SimpleDateFormat link](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) in the Datetime class's format method [documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexref.meta/apexref/apex_methods_system_datetime.htm#apex_System_Datetime_format), the pattern passed to this method allows 'E' which provides the English day name for the given date/time as 3 letters. In a date/time format, use of "E", "EE" or "EEE" generates the three letter short day names while "EEEE" or longer generates the full day names. The day names are *always* in English.

Thus, this if condition ensures that the (updated) `startDate` is neither a Saturday nor a Sunday and only then increments the total number of (week days) being counted.

Comment: Thanxs for the information.

Comment: Can you please tell me if I want to debug the code what should I write?

Comment: Apex.getWorkingDays(dateTime.now(), dateTime.now()+6);
For now I m writing this code but I want to enter date instead of dateTime.now() in startDate and endDate.

Comment: Call the method using date/times created using `Datatime.newInstance` and passing in the required parameters.

Answer (score 0):

It is asking whether the given date (the updated startDate) is NOT a Saturday AND Sunday and only then incrementing the total.

which is wrong it can only be one so instead of && you should use ||

Comment: The suggestion to use OR (||) is wrong. The need is correctly stated as the start date is NOT Sat and the start date is NOT Sun. Using OR will mean every date is counted because any given date is always either NOT Sat OR NOT Sun.

Comment: Yes you are right, sorry my bad.